# Windows programmable virtual printer "device"

Tags: windows, service, printing, printers

I have no idea how this windows service called or how should I tag it.
But I have seen around some software driven printing devices/configurations at windows, like **Send to OneNote** or **Convert to PDF** *(from different pdf applications)*.

So I want to create one like this myself, lets say a virtual printer device that converts documents into PDF file.

How it called? Where I can find some information about it ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of these applications (on Windows) actually use the built-in Windows PostScript printer driver to produce a PostScript program from the application.

That is then sent to a virtual printer (in versions of Windows before Windows 10, a Port Monitor is used) which stores the program on disk. It then starts up a PostScript interpreter which is capable of creating a PDF file from a PostScript file. Notably these include Adobe Acrobat Distiller, the JAWS PostScript interpreter and Ghostscript. Because Ghostscript is open-source, it is probably the most widely used.

The alternative approach is to write a printer driver. This needs to accept OS native drawing operations (which differ according to the operating system) and then produce PDF equivalents for those drawing operations, and wrap the whole thing up as a PDF file.

The first solution is easiest, because it leverages the work other people (the OS vendor and the PostScript interpreter vendor) have done. The latter is, I think you'll find, **much** harder.

Of course, since Windows and MacOS can both now produce PDF files, it seems somewhat redundant to implement these now.

Comment: Wow , thanks for the information, first of all I'm not planning to convert PDFs or something, that was just an example :) 
I'll start reading about *Windows PostScript printer driver* then ,
Thanks again.

Comment: If you don't want, specifically, to create PDF files, then you almost certainly don;t want to use the PostScript printer driver. You need instead to create your own printer driver, which takes the OS drawing primitives and creates equivalents in whatever it is you want to output to. That's what the PostScript printer driver does, it takes the OS marking operations and creates a PostScript program that makes the same marks on a PostScript printer. An Epson driver would produce ESC/P output, etc.

Comment: I forgot to add that the Windows Device Driver Development Kit (DDK) does, or at least used to, contain a wealth of information which is absolutely crucial to developing a printer driver.

Comment: In case I want that printer driver to be able to transfer/send files via RESTfull service, you think that would be possible to implement it using DDK? Or it would be to much of work to do and maybe it would be easier to program some device like rapsberry pi , to act like a printer and do all the job behind the scene ?

Comment: Its hard to say, not knowing what you want to achieve exactly, I alos have no idea what RESTfull is....

Comment: I need my printer device to be able to upload a file instead of printing it, to a service that has REST API, with a simple POST request.

Comment: Hmmm... It sounds to me like 'printing' isn't really what you want to do. If you take (say for example) a PDF file, and open it in Acrobat. When you print it, what happens is that the application draws the visual representation of the content on a Printer Device Context (created to be compatible with a specific printer) then tells that DC to render itself to the printer. The printer device driver then takes those drawing operations and creates content suitable for the printer. Could be a bitmap, could be a new PDF file, one thing it won't be is the original file.

Comment: The print API (on Windows at least) has no access to the original file, just whatever the application chooses to send to the print pipeline.